# Как на GiHub изменить стандартную страницу 404?

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, github

Когда я пытаюсь добавить файл **.htaccess**, мне выдает ошибку **"This file is hidden."** Что делать?

Comment: Об этом есть аж целая отдельная страница в документации https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site

Answer (score 0):

Для этого создайте `404.html` или `404.md`:

```
> index.html
> 404.html
  ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]